# How to parse a big JSON

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to parse a big JSON and I only need few things from it.
I've been trying to beautify it but I'm having trouble also because it seems that's not completely correct.
This is the [website](https://pastebin.com/NyZfKHPk)
and I've tried to delete all the unnecessary json
ending up with

```
[
   [
      "updateGlobalData",
      {
         "backgroundData":{
            "cities":[
               {
                  "type":"city",
                  "name":"Polis",
                  "id":186979,
                  "level":35,
                  "ownerId":"99253",
                  "ownerName":"D3vil666",
                  "ownerAllyId":"0",
                  "hasTreaties":0,
                  "actions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "state":"vacation",
                  "viewAble":1,
                  "infestedByPlague":false
               },
               {
                  "type":"city",
                  "name":"London",
                  "id":378440,
                  "level":28,
                  "ownerId":"242906",
                  "ownerName":"Mattia",
                  "ownerAllyId":"5541",
                  "ownerAllyTag":"LORDS",
                  "hasTreaties":0,
                  "actions":[
                     
                  ],
                  "state":"",
                  "viewAble":2,
                  "infestedByPlague":false
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
]
```

The properties I'm looking for are "State" and "ownerName".
State can be "vacation" like  ""state"": ""vacation"" or "" like ""state"": """"
These properties are often repeated so I'm only looking for to parse them only once.
For example:
I want to know which state Mattia has and it should return "nothing".
Which state D3vil666 has and it should return "vacation".

The code I'm using:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Class GlobalData
        Public Class BackgroundData
            Public Property Cities As List(Of City)
        End Class

        Public Class City
            Public Property Type As String
            Public Property Name As String
            Public Property OwnerName As String
            Public Property State As String
        End Class

        Public Property BackgroundDataa As BackgroundData
    End Class

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim client As New WebClient()
        Dim jsonString As String = client.DownloadString("https://s10-it.ikariam.gameforge.com/?view=updateGlobalData&islandId=1649&backgroundView=island&currentIslandId=1649&actionRequest=90983fef22b312ff7cbd51f0183bc301&ajax=1")

        Dim data As List(Of GlobalData) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of GlobalData))(jsonString)
        Dim state = data(0).BackgroundDataa.Cities.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.OwnerName = "Mattia").State
        MsgBox(state)
    End Sub
End Class
```

but I'm getting the error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Ikariam_VM.Form1+GlobalData' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path '[0]', line 1, position 2.'

I'm working on winform App for .net6+ and using the nuget Newtonsoft package to handle the json.

Any idea?
Thanks

edit1:

Code after suggestions

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net.WebRequestMethods
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSType
Imports System.Text.Json
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1



    Public Class GlobalData
        Public Class BackgroundData
            Public Property Cities As List(Of City)
        End Class

        Public Class City
            Public Property Type As String
            Public Property Name As String
            Public Property OwnerName As String
            Public Property State As String
        End Class
    End Class
        Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            Dim client As New WebClient()
            Dim jsonString As String = client.DownloadString("https://s10-it.ikariam.gameforge.com/?view=updateGlobalData&islandId=1649&backgroundView=island&currentIslandId=1649&actionRequest=90983fef22b312ff7cbd51f0183bc301&ajax=1")

            Dim jArr = JArray.Parse(jsonString)

            Dim cities = TryCast(jArr(0).OfType(Of JObject)() _
                   .Select(Function(p) p.Properties().Where(Function(p) p.Name = "backgroundData").First()) _
                   .FirstOrDefault().Value("cities"),
                 JArray)

            Dim state As String = Nothing

            If cities IsNot Nothing Then
                state = CStr(cities.Where(Function(c) CStr(c("OwnerName") = "D3vil666")) _
                           .FirstOrDefault()("state"))
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Please share at least one full JSON object. If you have a JSON array, we need at least one complete object from that array leading up to the value you are after. That said, if you are only looking for a specific state, you could just use the string of JSON and parse through it for exactly the words you are looking for.

Comment: I'm quite a newbie using Json, I m not really sure about what you are asking.. but whichever way to parse the words i'm looking for would be good to me

Comment: Post your entire JSON object instead of just what you've modified it to. The JSON in your OP is not valid.

Comment: You can find the entire JSON in the website link I've posted https://s10-it.ikariam.gameforge.com/?view=updateGlobalData&islandId=1649&backgroundView=island&currentIslandId=1649&actionRequest=90983fef22b312ff7cbd51f0183bc301&ajax=1

Comment: The url gives an error.

Comment: oh sorry https://pastebin.com/NyZfKHPk

Comment: You're missing the Root object. A class with `BackgroundData` as Property -- When you paste a JSON here, try not to take the string representation from the VS string viewer, it contain double-double quotes. Print the JSON to the Output panel and copy the JSON from there

Comment: tbh Jimi, Im quite lost here :). . .
I didn't use the website from the previous question because I've realized it doesn't update immediately the things from ikariam.com.. Now another issue, you can't see the link i've posted in this question prior the pastebin one, because of the "&actionRequest=90983fef22b312ff7cbd51f0183bc301&ajax=1" which means I'm the only able to see it but I must be logged to ikariam.com in order to make it works, otherwise I will see the error too. Wondering which kind of calls does https://ikalogs.ru/ to ikariam.com in order to retrieve data w/out a "action request"..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any custom classes to get data you need from a json string you posted. I haven't a VB.Net compillator so I post my code in c#. I hope you will find somebody to tranclate it to VB.Net

```cs
    var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);

    var cities = jArr[0].OfType<JObject>()
                   .Select(p => p.Properties().Where(p => p.Name == "backgroundData").First())
                   .FirstOrDefault().Value["cities"] as JArray;
                   
    string state=null;
    
    if (cities != null)
        state = (string)cities.Where(c => (string)c["ownerName"] == "D3vil666")
                         .FirstOrDefault()["state"]; // "vacation"
```

Comment: Thanks Serge but i receive the error  I receive the error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<TSource>(...) returned Nothing. in the lines Dim cities = TryCast(jArr(0).OfType(Of JObject)() _                .Select(Function(p) p.Properties().Where(Function(q) q.Name = "backgroundData").First()) _                .FirstOrDefault().Value("cities"),              JArray)

Comment: @Mattia I am sorry but my c# code was tested and working properly. I can not help you with  VB.Net code, it is better to ask Craig from the answer above

Comment: @craig lol guys

Answer (score 0):

Serge's answer, translated into VB:

```vb
Dim jArr = JArray.Parse(json)

Dim cities = TryCast(jArr(0).OfType(Of JObject)() _
               .Select(Function(p) p.Properties().Where(Function(q) q.Name = "backgroundData").First()) _
               .FirstOrDefault().Value("cities"),
             JArray)

Dim state As String = Nothing

If cities IsNot Nothing Then
    state = CStr(cities.Where(Function(c) CStr(c("OwnerName") = "D3vil666")) _
                       .FirstOrDefault()("state"))
End If
```

I think this is a spot where VB still needs the continuation characters to handle the lines properly.

Comment: Thanks, but Im having an error:
Description
Lambda parameter 'p' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression.

This  a part, I think something it is missing like suggested from Jimi "root object is missing" but tbh I don't know how to fix it..

Comment: No, I think it's an issue where C# is more permissive than VB (which is unusual).  It looks like VB doesn't allow re-using the same name at different levels in a lambda expression.  I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Craig! It solved the issue. But at debug, I receive the error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<TSource>(...) returned Nothing.
 in the lines
`Dim cities = TryCast(jArr(0).OfType(Of JObject)() _
               .Select(Function(p) p.Properties().Where(Function(q) q.Name = "backgroundData").First()) _
               .FirstOrDefault().Value("cities"),
             JArray)`

Comment: Not sure about that.  I just translated the answer from C# to VB.  Try asking on the C# answer?

Comment: see sergei comment lol

Comment: Will take another look if I have time for it.

Comment: @Mattia I built it in VB and did not see your error.  I literally copied and pasted the code in the answer.  (I commented out the state assignment because of a conflict with `Option Strict` which is surprising since it passed C#, but your error was earlier than that.)